# Emacs - How do I get projectile to open file in current window?

Tags: emacs

I've spent a whole day on this now. Say I open emacs and press `C-c p p` to open `projectile-switch-project` then `RET` to select a project, emacs opens a new window horizontally (on top of the previous) with the current buffer.

What I need is for projectile to use the already existing window and not open a new one. I've gone through every single line of my config and can figure out what is causing it.

I'd have posted my config but it's split over multiple files which will make it impractical to link to here.

The related packages I can think of which I use are:
projectile,
ivy swiper counsel - trilogy

What I've tried so far is start emacs without loading (ivy swiper counsel) and also I've tried replacing all my projectile code with bare minimum:

```
(use-package projectile
  :ensure t
  :init
  (projectile-mode +1)
  :bind (:map projectile-mode-map
              ("s-p" . projectile-command-map)
              ("C-c p" . projectile-command-map)))
```

which didn't work either.

I'm not expecting any specifics since it's a hand crafted config however I'm hoping for general pointes as to where to look for the possible cause.

Answer (score 1):

I'm researching more to see if i can find a better way for you, but this is what i have so far...

If you want to look around the customization options just type `M-x customize`. I found a ton of options you can browse through. Projectile was listed under "Convenience" and frames/windows were listed under "Environment". You can also search packages you might be interested in for more customization if you have MELPA installed.

Considering the way that buffers and windows work I don't think you can just replace the content inside the buffer with the content of another file. I think (or at least how I've been using Emacs) you will always open a new buffer to open a file and close old buffers if needed.

From what I was reading, buffers are like interfaces between Emacs and the file you're peering into. It sets up a connection, points to the file, and creates a name for the buffer (usually from the file name unless you change it). Something I find interesting is you can even have multiple buffers open to the same file and as you type on the screen in one buffer the text should show up in the other buffer in real time.

I was reading some documentation on it and I think the command you're looking for is `C-x C-f` or `C-x d`, which opens DiredMode. The first one opens your home directory and the second opens the current directory for the file in your selected buffer. This will open a mini-buffer to search through files and when you choose the file it should open the file in a new buffer on top of the buffer you were looking at initially.

Then you can use `C-x b` to list and move between other buffers that are already open.

Also, `M-x projectile-find-file` is a command you can use to search files and get the same outcome. I don't have that set to a key-binding so I don't know if there is a default, plus I'm using Spacemacs with evil-mode, so not everything is the same as original Emacs.

Also, maybe look into extension you can get from MELPA like Treemacs